# Bring a tensor in a (None,a,b) form in tensorflows functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer

I am using tensorflow with the [Functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional)
which is passing tensors of the form

```
(None, a,b)
```

between the layers. For a custom layer, I want to use fundamental operations which always yield products
of the form

```
(a,b)
```

In order to have a consistent solution, I need to bring it into the form `(None,a,b)`, too.
How do I do that in the current version of tensorflow. Many current solutions do not work, because
concepts like placeholders seem to not be available anymore.

This error makes the tensorflow Functional API useless if one wants to add custom elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a reshape layer in between,
check : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

Comment: That does not work, despite the fact, that they claim something else on this page. It does not add a None dimension if not already existent.

Comment: Another solution i would try is reshaping the tensor inside the privious custum layer

Comment: Tried everything, but i don't know how to introduce a "None" dimension, that is a placeholder in the Functional API.

Comment: What is the reason that you want first dim is None and not 1 for example?

Comment: None is only a placeholder in the functional API and is filled with the batch size while training. I wonder, why not more people have the same problem. There seems to be no solution to creating a tensor starting with None.

Comment: Yes i got your issue , i never work with the functional API and googling about it there is no way to get tensorf shape starting with None, perhaps u could add tf.keras.Input layer cuz it add None to batch seize by default